# Mostrar datos de eventos relativos a un calendario a través de la API de wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, google-api

Tengo un calendario de google integrado en una web de wordpress, pero no sé como acceder a los datos del calendario, en este caso, los eventos a través de la API de wordpress. Me he metido en [la documentación técnica de la API de wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) y la verdad es que no he visto nada relativo a calendarios. Así que empiezo a pensar que tal vez tenga que usar la API de google para acceder a la información de los eventos. Mi pregunta es ¿Hay algún modo de acceder a la información de un calendario sin usar la API de google, usando solo la API de wordpress?

Comment: No sé si puedas hacer eso mediante Wordpress, de todos modos me pregunto, en caso de que se pueda, ¿por qué usar una copia cuando puedes usar el original? La API propia de Google Calendar funcionará siempre mejor que una eventual API intermediaria. Luego puedes trabajar el contenido para exponerlo mediante la API de Wordpress, como haces con el resto del contenido de tu página.

Comment: @A.Cedano: Tienes razón. Me gusta conocer con detalle cada tecnología, pero tienes razón en mi caso, es mejor que haga esa parte con la API de google.